# optimising/simplifying cursor sql

Tags: sql, cursor

i've got the below code, and it operates just fine, only it takes a couple of seconds to calculate the answer - i was wondering whether there is a quicker/neater way of writing this code - and if so, what am i doing wrong?

thanks

```
select case when
    (select LSCCert from matterdatadef where ptmatter=$Matter$) is not null then
    (
        (select case when
            (SELECT top 1 dbo.matterdatadef.ptmatter 
             From dbo.workinprogress, dbo.MatterDataDef 
             where  ptclient=(
                 select top 1 dbo.workinprogress.ptclient 
                 from dbo.workinprogress 
                 where dbo.workinprogress.ptmatter = $matter$)
               and dbo.matterdatadef.LSCCert=(
                 select top 1 dbo.matterdatadef.LSCCert 
                 from dbo.matterdatadef 
                 where dbo.matterdatadef.ptmatter = $matter$)
             )=ptMatter then (
                 SELECT isnull((DateAdd(mm, 6, (
                         select top 1 Date 
                         from OfficeClientLedger 
                         where (pttrans=3) 
                             and ptmatter=$matter$ 
                         order by date desc))), 
                     (DateAdd(mm, 3, (
                         SELECT DateAdd 
                         FROM LAMatter 
                         WHERE  ptMatter = $Matter$)))
             )
        )
        end 
        from lamatter 
        where ptmatter=$matter$)
    )
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this your sql was generated from a reporting tool. The problem is you are executing the `SELECT top 1 dbo.matterdatadef.ptmatter...` query for *every row* of table `lamatter`. Further slowing execution, within that query you are recalculating comparison values for both ptclient and LSCCert - values that aren't going to change during execution.

Better to use proper joins and craft the query to execute each part only once by avoiding *correlated subqueries* (queries that reference values in joined tables and must be executed for every row of that table). Calculated values are OK, as long as they are calculated only once - ie from within the final where clause.

Here is a trivial example to demonstrate a *correlated subquery*:

Bad sql:

```
select a, b from table1 
where a = (select c from table2 where d = b)
```

Here the sub-select is run for every row, which will be slow, especially without an index on table2(d)

Better sql:

```
select a, b from table1, table2
where a = c and d = a
```

Here the database will scan each table at most once, which will be fast